# Get window handle from QT on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa

I am looking for an equivalent of this solution from SDL to get the window handle from QT(5.12) on OSX (Mojave)

```
  SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo = {};
  SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmInfo);
  mInfo.info.cocoa.window;
```

I tried a solution which I found on stack

```
NSWindow* window  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(500, 500, 500, 500)
      styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask |  NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask
      backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
      defer:NO];
```

But it fails with the error message

```
expected variable name or this in lambda capture list
```

I tried it via the QWidget

```
QWidget window;
window.resize(320, 240);
window.show();
window.winId()
window.windowHandle()
```

I tried to use the QMacNativeWidget but it failed, too.

I tried to fool around with this imports

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <AppKit/NSWindow.h>
```

But NSWindow.h throws a lot of error messages. It complains for example about missing braces.

So I can't find any documentation which helps me and I am working after the try and error principle which is not the most productive one^^

Maybe one of you had already the same issue and could provide some help or reference

Comment: So I removed the steps above since #import is a Microsoft thing and the other code requires .mm files but I want to use .cpp files.Qt offers a function called QWindow::fromWinId() which returns a NSView* instead of a NSWindow... Is there a way to transform a NSView into a NSWindow

Comment: NSView has a [window](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483301-window?language=objc) property